# Microsoft Detours hook WriteFile

Tags: c++, hook, lib, writefile, detours

When I hook WriteFile via Microsoft Detours, it works:

```
  DetourTransactionBegin();
  DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
  DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)Real_WriteFile, Hooked_WriteFile);
  DetourTransactionCommit();
```

However, when I look at the output in Debugview, two things are interesting:

1. Notepad calls WriteFile extremely frequently, because every time I type a symbol, it calls WriteFile, while I would expect it to call functions other than WriteFile to output symbols to the screen. Is this normal behavior? Because when I check the arguments of the WriteFile call, no data is written to disk.
2. But more importantly, with Detours I hooked WriteFile, but supposedly it also hooks NtWriteFile, which is a bit strange, because WriteFile is the function that calls NtWriteFile, not the other way around. When I run notepad.exe in API monitor, it looks like notepad.exe calls NtWriteFile directly in some cases, but for some reason my detours hook also seems to hooks those calls, while I only hook WriteFile. Can anyone explain this behaviour? Like, why does Detours also seem to hook NtWriteFile, while I explicitly specified to hook WriteFile?

[image]

Comment: Note:  Notepad++ and other applications may call `WriteFile` to record changes.  The question would be "how often".  You want an editor to be able to recover your changes and this is one method.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thank you, I mistakenly looked at the numberofbyteswritten of WriteFile and thought it was NULL based on the screenshot, but I should of course have looked at the arguments of NtWriteFile (face palm). So the written data is not NULL. Anyway, just to confirm Thomas, is your answer a possibility or are you pretty sure this is why notepad.exe calls WriteFile so often?

Comment: It's a possibility, since I didn't write Notepad++ or Notepad.  I've written editors though.